# Composer not recognized in CLI

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, command-line-interface

So i just installed composer.  Added a composer.bat file in with my php.exe file.  Restarted WAMP just in case but I still get "'composer' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file".

What am I missing?  Seems that I have hit roadblock after roadblock in trying to learn laravel...  I just want to code!

Comment: The best possible road here is to get acquainted with `homestead`. Then you can finally code at peace.

Answer (score 1):

Composer is a command line tool, so restarting wamp is irrelevant here.

You can install composer to any directory you want, and it doesn't have to be in the same directory as php.exe, just make sure to update your PATH variable to include both **the directory that contains php.exe** & **the directory that contains composer binaries**

You can update your PATH variable by "Right Click on My Computer" -> "Properties" -> "Advanced System Settings" -> "Environment Variables"

You may update the PATH variable for either the currently logged-in user or for all users (a.k.a System Variables) whichever you prefer ... once finished if you already have a cmd window open close it & open a new window.